# Avarage Speed conventional formula VS Mean Value of Multiple Speeds

Tags: homework-and-exercises, speed

Here the basic problem:

The motion of an extraordinarily jubilant bird flying straight up and down is given by the graph below, which shows the vertical position y as a function of time t.

What was the average speed of the bird between t=0 and t=10?

[image]

Ok i know that the solution is the Sum of all the Distances / Total Time:

Avarage Speed =  5 + 0 + 4 / 10 = 0.9

But what if instead of use the formula, i find the mean value of all the speeds?

Doing so i want to share with you what i did, and ask you if you have a better explanation of mine. Honestly i founded hard to understand at first and i kind of went through it by intuition but is not 100% clear... here my steps:

So looking in the graph to find the mean value that would be:

s1 = 5/2.5 = 2

s2 = ( i don t count it cause is zero, i will add the time is s3 time )

s3 = 4/7.5 = 0.533333333333333

Avarage Speed = (2 + 0.533333333333333)/2 = 1.266666666666667

But 0.9 !== 1.266666666666667 !!! i was really surprised!

To find a solution i thought that because the elapsed times between one record and the other are different, this create a non proportional record of the two speeds, so i  make them proportional multiply each speed with a time ratio between 0 and 1, here my solution:

(TimeRatio = 1/(Tot Time/Record1 Time)

TimeRatio1 =  1/(10 / 2.5 ) = 1/4 = 0.25

TimeRatio2 =  1/(10 / 7.5 ) = 1/1.3333333333 = 0.750000001875

now i add s1*TimeRatio1 to s2*TimeRatio2 and i find the mean value dividing all for 2

(2*0.25 + 0.533333333333333*0.750000001875)/2  = 0.900000001/2 = 0.4500000005

and here i finally have the mean value of the two speed proportionated to their time.

Now to have the real value of the mean speed i need to multiply this value for two, because i separate the total time in two parts corresponding of the two record taken, so we got   0.4500000005*2 = 0.900000001 ... much more similar to the first 0.9 :)

You have a better explanation? i am a software programmer, so i never really studied physic or math deeply, if you can explain better would be really appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not just add the two speeds and divide by 2, since it was traveling at 2 meters per second for only 25% of the time, not 50%.

Comment: Yes, actually is totally understandable now.

Comment: I think as a software developer i most of the time use to calcultate monodimensional quantities, instead in physic you got multidimensional quantities to take in consideration,  like time and space inside speed. Hope my question will be usefull to people like me ise to don t think in physic term.

Comment: It's not even really a physics thing, more of the mathematics of a weighted average, the same thing is done with students grades